# creating multiple side-by-side blocks

Tags: align, tcolorbox, boxes

I want to create multiple colored boxes side by side in article format as I have shared the link below. I would be very happy if you could help me on how to do it. As you can see, some boxes have gaps just below them, so I have no idea how to align them. The images at the end don't matter, I just don't know how to create colored boxes side by side and how to align it if the bottom of a box is empty. Even the first two lines of boxes will be enough to understand the logic.

I'm grateful for all the ideas in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a `tabular` of `tcolorboxes` is enough

```
\documentclass[a0paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    mybox/.style={
        sharp corners,
        colbacktitle=#1!70,
        colback=#1!20,
        nobeforeafter,
        height=3cm,
        valign=top,
        width=2cm,
    }
}

\newtcolorbox{graybox}[2][]{mybox=gray, title=#2, #1}

\newtcolorbox{brownbox}[2][]{mybox=brown, title=#2, #1}

\newtcolorbox{bluebox}[2][]{mybox=blue, title=#2, #1}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{cc@{}cc@{}c@{}c}
\begin{graybox}{Box}
Some text
\end{graybox}
&
\begin{brownbox}{Box}
Some text
\end{brownbox}
&
&
\begin{bluebox}{Box}
Some text
\end{bluebox}
&
\begin{bluebox}{Box}
Some text
\end{bluebox}
\\
\begin{graybox}{Box}
Some text
\end{graybox}
&
\begin{brownbox}{Box}
Some text
\end{brownbox}
&
\begin{brownbox}{Box}
Some text
\end{brownbox}
&
\begin{bluebox}{Box}
Some text
\end{bluebox}
&
\begin{bluebox}{Box}
Some text
\end{bluebox}
&
\begin{bluebox}{Box}
Some text
\end{bluebox}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]